# Javascript change class upon input - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the class of a form upon user input. I am using twitter bootstrap so i want to use their validation style. Can't figure out why this isn't working:

```
    <!--html-->
    <script src="../js/customjs.js"></script>

    ...some code



<form id="formular">

<input type="text" class = "form-control" name = "Navn" placeholder = "Virksomhedsnavn*"  onChange="changeClass()"/> 

</form>

(my script)
 (function changeClass() {
         document.getElementById("formular").onchange = function()
            this.className += "has-success";
    }
```

Comment: You have multiple same ID's -- that's illegal and will mess up your JS

Answer (score 0):

ID's **must** be unique! `document.getElementById` expects only 1 element to match, therefore will return only the top matching element! Also, it's better to keep JS out of the HTML, too many inline handlers are very ugly to maintain:

```
document.getElementById("formular").onchange = function() {
    this.className += "has-success";
}
```

Comment: Ok now i have changed my code but it's still not working:

<form id="formular">

<input type="text" class = "form-control" name = "Navn" placeholder = "Virksomhedsnavn*"  onChange="changeClass()"/> 

</form>

(my script)
 (function changeClass() {
         document.getElementById("formular").onchange = function()
   this.className += "has-success";
 }

Comment: @user2986819 -- Looks like you may need some beginner courses in JS -- remove your inline `onChange` handlers, and change the ID of the above handler to match the ID of your `input` that you want affected